# Webpack + angular2

Tags: typescript, angular, webpack

What is the meaning of this error ? After bundling angular2 app with webpack
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"    in bundel.js 1.

What is that I am missing. I have added all the necessary loaders.

```
// webpack.config.js
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

//const TARGET = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;

module.exports = {
  //context: __dirname + '/public',
  entry: './public/components/boot/boot.ts',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('dist/'), // This is where images AND js will go
    publicPath: 'public/', // This is used to generate URLs to e.g. images
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("bundle.css")
  ],
  module: {
    //
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.json/,
        loader: 'json-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
      },
      { test: /\.(png|jpg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192' }, // inline base64 for <=8k images, direct URLs for the rest
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style", "css!postcss")
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: [/node_modules/],
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style", "css!postcss!sass?outputStyle=expanded")
      },
      // fonts and svg
      { test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
      { test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
      { test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream" },
      { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "file" },
      { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml" },
      {
        test: /\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif)$/,
        loader: 'file'
      } // inline base64 for <=8k images, direct URLs for the rest
    ]
  },
  postcss: function(webpack) {
    return [
      autoprefixer({browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'ie >= 9', 'and_chr >= 2.3']})
    ]
  },
  sassLoader: {
    includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules")]
  },
  resolve: {
    // now require('file') instead of require('file.coffee')
    extensions: ['', '.ts', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.js', '.json', 'es6']
  },
  devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

Not able to debug this error

Comment: The error doesn't seem to be there. How does your index look like?

Comment: Are you seeing the error at runtime or build time? If it's the former it could simply be that your server is incorrectly serving your index.html instead of the bundle.js so the browser tries to evaluate html as js?

Comment: You should share your bundle.js if it's created. This could be caused by anything. Internal or external libraries as you are bundling the whole thing.

Answer (score 4):

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

This is most likely an error:

1. in your TypeScript
2. being raised as a compiler error to webpack
3. being reported to you.

Answer (score 2):

Check this good Angular2 Webpack sample

[Angular 2 Webpack sample](https://github.com/manjunathshetty/angular2-webpack-sample)

This github project demonstrates how to use Webpack with Angular2 with minimal configurations.

Here is the sample of Webpack config from this project

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./main.ts",
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "./dist/bundle.js"
    },
    resolve : {
        extentions: ['','.js','.ts']
    },
    module: {
        loaders : [{
            test: /\.ts/, loaders : ['ts-loader'],exclude: /node_modules/
        }]
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, that error appears because in some import, the name or the file type is wrong.

Do you have html imports?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<!doctype html>` on top of your template (HTML).